# Python Selenium: XPath changes the encoding of my variables

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, utf-8

I has this code that searches through text by XPath. The problem is that the searched text may contain Latin characters like `ñ`or `í`.

I encoded it and when I print it, it shows perfectly, but when I use the XPath the encoding changes, and obviously it can't be found.

The decoded var prints well:

```html
nombre_act = "HOTEL DIEGO DE ALMAGRO SAN PEDRO DE ATACAMA"
nombre_act = nombre_act.decode("utf8")

nombre_contrato = "Campaña Cyber Day, Desayuno Incluído"
nombre_contrato = nombre_contrato.decode("utf8")
print nombre_contrato

xpath = "//select[@name='"+nombre_act+"']/option[text()='"+nombre_contrato+"']"
print xpath
hotel_sel = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

[image: console]

Comment: Adding html sample will help to provide exact answer

Answer (score 1):

Your code trials were near perfect. However I feel you don't need to change through encoding/decoding unless you want to print the characters to the console as follows:

```
nombre_act_actual = "HOTEL DIEGO DE ALMAGRO SAN PEDRO DE ATACAMA"
#nombre_act = nombre_act_actual.encode("utf-8")

nombre_contrato_actual = "Campaña Cyber Day, Desayuno Incluído"
nombre_contrato = nombre_contrato_actual.encode("utf-8") #required as you need to print to the console
print nombre_contrato

xpath = "//select[@name='"+nombre_act_actual+"']/option[text()='"+nombre_contrato_actual+"']"
hotel_sel = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

However, your another issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.41*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.41*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v67-69**

- You are using *chrome=70.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.44*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.44/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v69-71**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.41* and the *Chrome Browser v70.0*

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.44**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v69-71*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.44 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.44/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.